# initexmf.exe problem when installing lipsum

Tags: installing, windows, protext

I was always afraid of using TeX, but now I have to, in order to put formulas graphically perfect in Corel Draw, which has nothing else to do it. And just as I thought, even by following step by step a simple, official tutorial, everything goes wrong at once:

- I want to use the `\lipsum[1-7]` command
- it says "undefined control sequence" when compiling
- I try searching for the lipsum package on my repository, I find it, try to install it
- it starts, and then says "the operation failed for some reason", and then `Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe`. (that "some reason" is a deliberate cruelty of the programmer, you have to recognize it!)

Now, what to I do with that? Just as I thought, TeX is such a jungle that it beats any programming language at the insanity of the debugging! It was just a simple tutorial, found [here](http://www.tug.org/begin.html), "first LaTeX document", with the latest installation of ProText, on Windows 7 64 bit! Simpler you cannot be! Why on earth does it have to be always so complicated!
I am sorry to be so angry, but I have very few time left to finish a poster, and just for a few stupid equations I will have to go through the most marathonian debugging immediatly...I don't have time for this right now! And nothing on google, as always!

EDIT: and now, in the package manager, I can **neither** install **nor** uninstall the lipsum package. But only in the normal mode, in the admin mode I can! But still with the stupid "initexmf.exe" error. I ANYONE could understand PRECISELY where the problem comes from, I would pray the god of insanity for a year

EDIT 2: found [this](http://old.nabble.com/Windows-API-error-1113-td31568325.html) which seemed to be close to my case, I have almost tracked down all traces of the unfortunate "ï" in my username, but the name of the personnal folder is very difficult to change, don't have the time to try right now. If it works I will let you know! Because with all the rest (computer name, account name everywhere etc) it did not change anything (of course!)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Sorry to hear you are having such a difficult time, but like all other software until you have it properly installed, and updated it may or may not work.  You don't provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so we can't really help you to figure out the problem.  But I would guess you were missing the `\usepackage{lipsum}` in the preamble (before `\begin{document]`) which is required to use the `\lipsum[1-7]` macro.

Answer (score 5):

Hm. Well to answer some of your questions:

1. initexmf fails sometimes (often because of problems with systems fonts which fc-cache can't handle), but quite often you can simply ignore the failure as it doesn't affect the part of the TeXSystem you are actually using.
2. Regarding admin and user mode: You have installed MikTeX in multiuser (which you needn't have done - miktex can be installed without problems in a restricted account only for one user). In such a setup packages installed as admin can only be deinstalled by the admin - a normal user is not allowed to deinstall packages used perhaps by other users.
3. LaTeX is a powerful system. And as every powerful system you don't master it when you are angry and under time pressure. Instead of fighting with LaTeX: Ask someone to generate your equations in the needed format.